How to fix VK_Tab in java?
I have a problem with KeyListener in java. Any key is woking, but 'Tab' key is not working. I dont know it's not working.
Here is my code :
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    static class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + e.getKeyCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    }
}



define "not working". What is it you are trying to do? what isn't working?

It is possible the <TAB> key can be associated along with some Swing components  (for example, a JTextField or a JButton) not just a window.

i mean, when i click any key in Frame then in my console have "Key Pressed:  " + keyCode. But when i click 'tap' key, it do not visible that
